# PHP for not loop for all values

Tags: php, for-loop, unset

I have this code snippet:

```
var_dump(count($xml)); // returns 34 

for($i = 8; $i < count($xml); $i++){ 
    echo "unseting $i <br>";
    unset($xml[$i]);
}

var_dump($xml);
```

### Result:

int 34

unseting 8 
unseting 9
unseting 10 
unseting 11 
unseting 12 
unseting 13 
unseting 14 
unseting 15 
unseting 16 
unseting 17 
unseting 18 
unseting 19 
unseting 20

Why is this for breaked at $i = 20 ?

When i change for-loop for $i = 0 - it's still works anomaly. I get only number 0-16 - simply always only half.  But when i comment unset line - then it's iterate over all values..

Where can be problem in unset? Why unset breaking my for at half?

Comment: Because you reduce the length of `$xml` in your loop

Comment: Oh well - it's work fine now! Many thanks!

Comment: You should accept an answer if you've satisfied by any answers below. It's often useful for future visitors that has similar problem to find which answer that solve the problem. http://i.stack.imgur.com/LkiIZ.png

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You'r experiencing this because [unset()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.unset.php) destroys the specified variables.
 So when you iterate over the loop and at the same time you're using **unset()** to remove the element from array, array size also decreases along with removing elements from array,

So execution goes like this,

```
unseting 8 with remaining array size: 34 
unseting 9 with remaining array size: 33 
unseting 10 with remaining array size: 32 
unseting 11 with remaining array size: 31 
unseting 12 with remaining array size: 30 
unseting 13 with remaining array size: 29 
unseting 14 with remaining array size: 28 
unseting 15 with remaining array size: 27 
unseting 16 with remaining array size: 26 
unseting 17 with remaining array size: 25 
unseting 18 with remaining array size: 24 
unseting 19 with remaining array size: 23 
unseting 20 with remaining array size: 22
```

Demo: https://eval.in/599426

Answer (score 1):

When you `unset` you're shifting the items in the array, and the array is shrinking as the loop is running.  What use to be at index `$i`, is now at index `$i - 1` essentially.

Try running the loop backwards, and using `$i--` instead.

```
for($i = count($xml); $i > 7; $i--){ 
    echo "unseting $i <br>";
    unset($xml[$i]);
}
```

You can also set the length before the loop runs so it's not changing during the loop like this:

```
$count = count($xml);
for ($i = 8; $i < $count; $++) {
    ...
}
```

Comment: $max = count($xml);
  
for($i = 8; $i < $max; $i++){ ... } Works fine! Many thanks! :-)

Answer (score 0):

`unset` removes elements from your indexed array, making the `count()` result decrease, influencing the end-condition of your `for` loop.

If your intension is to remove array elements from a certain index onwards, then you can just use [`array_splice`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-splice.php):

```
array_splice($xml, 8);
```